# How to write a regular expression?

Tags: regular-expressions

I am trying to write a regular expression for the set of all strings in $\Sigma^*$ that starts with an even number of $b$'s and contains at most two $a$'s.  The language contains only $a$'s and $b$'s.

This is what I have figured out so far:

$b^*$ - language with exactly $0$ $a$'s;

$b^*ba^*$ - language with exactly one $a$;

$b^*ba^*ba$ - language with exactly two $a$'s;

$bb^*$ - language starting with an even number of $b$'s.

I'm not sure where to go with this (or if how I have defined the language starting with an even number of $b$'s right).  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does your alphabet only contain $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Yes it does, sorry I will add it into the question

Comment: Then in Perl syntax your regular expression is "(bb)*(ab*a?b*)?"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Perl syntax?  I think I'm looking for (bb)*(b*)*(b*ba*)*(b*ba*ba)

Comment: No, not really. Your regular expression matches for example the string "bbb" which doesn't start with an even number of b's. But thats just one of the problems it has. Look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) for what I mean by Perl syntax.

Comment: in the syntax of regular expressions, the answer of TooOldForMath translates to $(bb)^*ab^*(a+\epsilon)b^*$ which is almost right, you might want to add $+(bb)^*$ at the end if it is allowed to have just an even number of $b$ and no $a$.

Comment: an other way to put it is $(bb)^*(\epsilon+ab^*+ab^*ab^*)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the help!  I have been so confused as to what the syntax is.  In class I haven't seen the use of + so I have had a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having this question eternally unanswered, here is the answer proposed by Denis in the comments:
$$(bb)^*(\epsilon + ab^* + ab^*ab^*)$$